# How can I differentiate between validations in a form and display error message related to each validation separately?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-4

Here is what i did...

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
<!-- NAME -->
<div ng-class="{'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine }">

  <label>Name</label>

  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id = "focusedInput" ng-model="user.name" required>
  <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">Your name is required.</p>
</div>

<!-- USERNAME -->
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.username.$invalid && !userForm.username.$pristine }">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" required id = "focusedInput" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8">
    <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Username is too short.</p>
    <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Username is too long.</p>
  <p ng-show="userForm.username.$invalid && !userForm.username.$pristine" class="help-block">Your Username is required.</p>

</div>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>

</form>
```

I tried to use similar validation for username field when it is left empty, as i did for name field. But the problem is : both the error messages related to name and username are getting printed at the start upto minimum length condition of the username field. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Pretty sure ng-messages will help with this as well https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages has it's own module so needs to be included separately and loaded as a dependency but shows only one element at a time from the list of messages and is made to work with the $error object.

Answer (score 1):

Add the $dirty check to your ng-show. De $dirty flag is true when a user manipulated the form.

```
<p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.minlength && userForm.username.$dirty" class="help-block">Username is too short.</p>
```